# Using iOS Keychain Services to store additional values

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

Following this simple example http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html

I see that you use kSecAttrAccount to set the username you want to store and kSecValueData to set the password.  For my app I also want to store a four digit passcode similar to the passcode lock screen for iOS.  I'm not having a lot of luck finding where I can store an additional value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a 2nd `KeychainItemWrapper` instance with a different id. Use the `kSecValueData` value for your passcode.